# Wrong classification based on noun

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

Being a Honor phone user and only recently active on this site, I was checking out the posts related to this phone by searching for the "honor". I ran across [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55770/insufficient-storage-available-during-update?s=22|0.0604) which confused me till I realized "honor" here was used in a different context but the post got wrongly included in the search.

Minor maybe but just pointing out. Apologies if this is known or earlier reported.

Comment: So you're asking for a bot that differentiates between the implied and literal meanings or words in different contexts? This isn't the 25th century.

Comment: Repro'd on Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo, Yahoo, Yandex, Blackle, ChaCha, GoodSearch, AOL search, Sogu, Baidu, Naver, ask.com, ... But not Excite, ironically.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really possible for us to determine how the word is used and whether it's relevant to your search because a) that would require analyzing the content around it and attempting to determine if it was used as a verb or a noun and b) we don't know which form of the word *you* wanted to search for based on the search criteria provided.

All we can do is just display all posts where the word appeared and hope you can figure out which ones are relevant to you and which are not.

Alternatively, you could find an actual tag for whichever Honor device you are using, or perform a wildcard tag search for all of them, like so: [`[*honor*]`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*honor*) (which doesn't seem to be very useful in this case because questions about Honor devices don't seem to get tagged with it much)

Comment: Thanks, on hind sight realize what you say.. Please delete the post